# How to cut a vector in two of the same size?

Tags: r, vector, r-factor

So , I have a vector with length of 114:

```
p2<-c(28.00, 28.00, 28.00, 28.00, 28.00, 28.00, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37,
     28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37, 28.37,28.37, 28.37, 28.45,
     28.45, 28.45 ,28.45, 31.37, 31.37 ,31.37, 31.37, 31.37, 31.37, 31.37, 31.37,
     31.37, 31.37, 31.37, 31.37 ,31.37, 36.37, 36.37, 36.37 ,36.37, 38.00, 38.00,
     38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00,
     38.00 ,38.00, 38.00, 38.00 ,38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00,38.00, 38.00, 38.00,
     38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.00, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37,
     38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 38.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37,
     41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37,
     41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.3,7, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.37,
     41.37, 41.37, 41.37, 41.3)
```

and I want to cut it in two of the number of records. I've tried to use cut, but the output is defined by intervals with the same length: `(28,34.7]`   `(34.7,41.4]`

How do I do that?

Comment: What would be your expected output? Can you add the data in a reproducible way, i.e. `dput( p2 )`.

Comment: Did you try `p2[1:(length(p2)/2)]` and `p2[(1+length(p2)/2):length(p2)]`?

Comment: I expect the output to be a vector divided by two factor intervals with the same number of records

Comment: Or as a matrix: `p2mat <- matrix(p2, ncol=2)`

Comment: @JMarcelino what is your expected output for `p2 <- c(4,2,1,5)` for example?

Comment: He wants it cut at the `mean`.

Comment: @agstudy the output would be
[1] (1,2]   (4,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
library(Hmisc)
cut2(p2, g = 2)
```

From `?cut2`: ...if `cuts` are not given, will cut x into quantile groups (`g` given)

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear your expected output , but I think you look for:

```
split(p2,cut(p2,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case try

```
> set.seed(1)
> p2 <- runif(114, 28, 42)  # random data
> 
> ind <- 1:(length(p2)/2) # index for cutting the vector
> p2.1 <- p2[ind]         # first subvector
> p2.2 <- p2[-ind]        # second subvector
> 
> length(p2.1)            # length of first subvector
[1] 57
> length(p2.2)            # length of second subvector
[1] 57
```

Or maybe something like this?

```
> vec <- setNames(p2, cut(p2,2, labels=c("V1", "V2")))
> is.vector(vec)  # one vector 
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I've probably not explain my doubt clearly. I expect the output to be a vector divided by two factor intervals with the same number of records.